# Behavior Flow in Facebook analytics

Tags: facebook, facebook-analytics

Google Analytics got a very cool feature called: [Behavior Flow](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2785577?hl=en).
It helps you to understand the flow of your users in your app.

For example you got 4 screens that can be reached from each other and one event: ScreenOpen with one value screen name.
With **Behavior Flow** you will see all the possible charts out of those 4 events and more, you will see how many of the people who went to screens 1,2,3 will go to screen 1,2,3,4 after that, it breaks down each of the steps and you can easily zoom to where it interest you most.

I am familiar with Facebook charts, but I don't know how to get **Behavior Flow** out of it.

With charts or with some thing else, is there a way to achieve the **Behavior Flow** in Facebook Analytics?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook Analytics does not currently support **Behavior Flow**. The closest feature is Funnels, which will allow you to see how many people went through a specific path of a **Behavior Flow**. For example, you can create a funnel with four steps, each with the ScreenOpen event but with different parameters for each step (screen=1, screen=2, etc.). You will be able to see how many people who opened screen 1 also went on to open screen 2, and how many of those people went on to open screen 3, and finally how many of those people went on to open screen 4.

You can read about creating funnels here: https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/425400007621572